# Роутинг при отрисовке списка

Tags: vue.js

Во-первых, код почему-то не рендерится - помогите понят причину.
Во-вторых, как сделать так, чтобы при отрисовке списка каждому элементу назначался соответствующий путь из data в  в атрибут :to=""?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  chapters: [
     { chapter: 'First',  route: '/first1' },
      { chapter: 'Second', route: '/second2' },
      { chapter: "Third", route: '/third3' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

li {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <router-link tag="li" :to="" v-for="item,id in chapters">{{ item.chapter }}</router-link>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Подключите `vue-router`
2. Создайте компоненты для маршрутов.
3. Определите маршруты.
4. Создайте экземпляр маршрутизатора и передайте маршруты.
5. Создайте экземпляр приложения и передайте экземпляр созданного маршрутизатора.

```js
// 1в Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

// 2. Определяем компоненты для маршрутов.
const Home = {
  template: '<div>Номе page</div>'
}
const Chapter = {
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  template: '<div>Chapter {{ $route.params.id }}</div>'
}

// 3. Определяем маршруты.
const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home
}, {
  path: '/:id',
  name: 'chapter',
  component: Chapter
}]

// 4. Создаём экземпляр маршрутизатора
// и передаём маршруты.
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

// 5. Создаём экземпляр приложения.
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data: {
    chapters: [{
      id: 1,
      title: 'First'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Second'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      title: "Third"
    }]
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

li a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in chapters" :key="item.id">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'chapter', params: { id: item.id }}">{{ item.title }}</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<!-- 1а. Подключаем vue -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<!-- 1б. Подключаем vue-roter -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@3.0.6"></script>
```